# Printing multiple labels using Publisher interop

Tags: c#, visual-studio, printing, ms-office, publisher

I am looking for a way to print multiple labels on the same page using Microsoft Publisher. I am using Publisher 2013 and 2016 for development, but really any solution would be a good starting point.

An additional constraint is that the labels have a number field that has to be unique, so each item on the page will need to have a different number. I already have the code to generate the labels with different numbers, I just need to specify the print layout.

As an example, let's say I wanted 4 labels a page, the labels might be laid out like this:

NUMBER_1    NUMBER_3

NUMBER_2    NUMBER_4

Specific questions:

1. If I have a template for the desired page layout and I generate the labels programmatically, how would I specify, via interop, that each position gets a label with a different number?
2. Failing that, can I describe the page layout programmatically and "insert" each label with a unique number before sending the job to the printer?

Please let me know if I can provide further details.

Comment: If you provide an example file I can take a look

Answer (score 1):

In MS Publisher 2013, there is an option to print "Multiple Pages Per Sheet" when you go to use the File > Print console. When you change it to this option, you should see as many different pages as created in your document that each piece of paper can hold. Be sure your paper size and label spacing is correct. This should be all you need to do. If you want to do this in code, then I am not quite certain. Unfortunately, there are no developer templates for customizing Publisher in Visual Studio.